# ActionFilterAttribute scope call order

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, actionfilterattribute

I have problem with the call order of my ActionFilter.

I have created an Filter that set the layout MasterName:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Class, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class MasterNameAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public String MasterName { get; set; }

    public MasterNameAttribute(String masterName)
    {
        this.MasterName = masterName;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        viewResult.MasterName = this.MasterName;
```

I used it in my Controller this way:

```
[MasterName("_Layout_Main")]
public partial class ProjectController : BaseController
{        
    [MasterName("_Layout_Special")]
    public ActionResult Dashboard()
    {
```

No I have the problem that ASP MVC is calling the filters in order **Action-Scope -> Method-Scope**. But I want the Method-Scope filter is the result and override Controller-Scope filter.

**My question:**

1. In the MSDN is written that the filter are call in Enum value order of "AttributeTargets" Enum (Class = 4, Method = 0x40). Why is the Controller-Scope filter the last one called?
2. How can I solve my order problem without using "Order" property? <s>Is the a proper way to detect if a Methode-Scope filter of samt type exists?</s>

**Hints**

```
.ControllerDescriptor.IsDefined(...
```

Does not helped me, because my real implementation has some conditions if the MasterName is setted by the filter or not. So finding the Method-Scope Attribute does not tells me if the filter has been used or not and if the Controller-Scope filter should be used or not (only if Method-Scope filter where not used). So I think a proper call order would be the best solution.

**Related to @swapneel answere:**

No sorry this not matching my needs. I have a very complex layout selection that is best setted by attributes. I need inheritance, overwritting and order logic.

Like:

```
[MasterName("_Layout1", Host = "sub1.domain.com")]
[MasterName("_Layout2", Host = "sub2.domain.com")]
[MasterName("_Layout3", Host = "sub3.domain.com")]
public partial class ProjectController : BaseController
{
    [MasterName("_Layout_1_1", Host = "sub1.domain.com")]
    [MasterName("_Layout_2_1", Host = "sub2.domain.com")]
    public ActionResult Dashboard()
    {
```

Here a "Dashboard" Action call with host "sub2.domain.com" should overwrite the Controller defined "_Layout2" MasterName with "_Layout2_1". On all other actions it will not be overwritten and "_Layout2" is the active one.

Regards Steffen!

Answer (score 0):

this may not be in-relation with your question but I think

> If you want to set one or different Master-page for each view on run
>   time or on design time. you can use `_ViewStart.cshtml.`

---

The _ViewStart.cshtml file will execute at the start of each view's rendering. Any code contained within the code block in this file will execute before any code in the view. Typically, this file will set the layout template to be used by the views in the application:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

An MVC application can have multiple `_ViewStart.cshtml` files. The order in which these files execute is dependent upon the location of the files in the folder hierarchy and the particular view being rendered. The MVC Runtime will first execute the code in the `_ViewStart.cshtml` file located in the root of the Views folder. It will then work its way up the folder hierarchy, executing the code in each `_ViewStart.cshtml` file it finds along the way.   For example, if we had`_ViewStart.cshtml` files in the following locations:

Copied above text from  this link - [what-is-the-purpose-of-the-viewstartcshtml-file-and-how-is-it-used](http://www.brainthud.com/cards/5218/19522/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-viewstartcshtml-file-and-how-is-it-used)

Comment: No sorry this is not helping, please see extended initial question for more information.